# PHP for each function to print td

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

(Solution found, check at the end)
I have a database table called `CONTRIBUTION FEES`

| category | year | amount | program |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID FEE | 1 | 5 USD | SWT |
| TUITION FEE | 1 | 50 USD | SWT |
| TUITION FEE | 2 | 50 USD | SWT |
| TUITION FEE | 3 | 50 USD | SWT |
| EXAMINATION | 2 | 10 USD | SWT |

And i use the following php codes with mysqli to select data and display in html table

```
<?php  
           echo'<table class="table table-bordered table-sm" id="table">
      <thead>';
          
 include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/config.php"; 
                // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT year) AS years FROM `CONTRIBUTION FEES` WHERE program = '$program'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  $years = explode(',', $row['years']);
  if($row['years'] != ''){
 echo' <tr>
    <th>CATEGORY</th>';
     foreach ($years as $year){
     echo' <th>YEAR '.$year.'</th>';
            }
   echo' 
    <th>ACTIONS</th>
   </tr>';
  }

         
echo'
      </thead>
      <tbody>';
            


           
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category) AS categories,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT year) AS years,GROUP_CONCAT(amount) AS amounts FROM `CONTRIBUTION FEES` WHERE program = '$program' GROUP BY category";
$result = $conn->query($query);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $years = explode(',', $row['years']);
    $amounts = explode(',', $row['amounts']);
    $categories = explode(',', $row['categories']);
    
  foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $category . ' </td>';
           foreach ($years as $key => $year) {
          $amount = isset($amounts[$key]) ? $amounts[$key] : '0';
           echo '<td>' . $amount. '</td>';
}
     echo '<td><button>Edit</button></td>
    </tr>';
}
    
  }
    }else{
  
    }

  

 echo'
   </tbody>
    </table>';
     ?>
```

The challenge I am facing is to display each contribution to its associated year. Currently, the html table looks like this

| CATEGORY | YEAR 1 | YEAR 2 | YEAR 3 | ACTIONS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EXAMINATION | 10 USD |  |  | Edit |
| GRADUATION | 20 USD |  |  | Edit |
| ID FEE | 5 USD |  |  | Edit |
| TUITION FEE | 50 USD | 50 USD | 50 USD | Edit |

As you can see, GRADUATION is displayed in Year 1 column instead of Year 3 column and Examination is display in Year 1 instead of Year 2.

*Format I want*

| CATEGORY | YEAR 1 | YEAR 2 | YEAR 3 | ACTIONS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EXAMINATION |  | 10 USD |  | Edit |
| GRADUATION |  |  |  | Edit |
| ID FEE | 5 USD |  |  | Edit |
| TUITION FEE | 50 USD | 50 USD | 50 USD | Edit |

I was able to find a solution, Read @Khang Tran Answer.

````
       echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $category . ' </td>';
    foreach ($years as $year) {
   $yearKey = array_search($year, $categoryYears);

  if ($yearKey !== false && isset($amounts[$yearKey])) {
       $amount = $amounts[$yearKey];
   } else {
       $amount = '0';
  }

    echo '<td>' . $amount . '</td>';
}

     echo '<td><button>Edit</button></td>
    </tr>';
}```
````

Comment: check your table name

Comment: Step 1: Stop using GROUP_CONCAT. Step 2: Fetch your data into an array first, using the category as top level key, and the year as second. Step 3: Loop over your categories, inside have a for loop for the amount of years you need to cover. Check if your current "row" of data contains an entry for that year - if so, output the value, else an empty table cell ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the years of the first query in the second loop. So first, you change the name of the second $years, such as $categoryYears.

This is my solution. Hope it's useful for you

```
//....
$categoryYears = explode(',', $row['years']);
$amounts = explode(',', $row['amounts']);
$categories = explode(',', $row['categories']);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $category . ' </td>';
    //loop for all years of the first query
    foreach ($years as $key => $year) {
        //get the index of year in list years of the category
        if ($yearKey = array_search($year, $categoryYears) !== false) {
            $amount = isset($amounts[$yearKey]) ? $amounts[$yearKey] : '0';
        } else {
            $amount = '0';
        }
   
        echo '<td>' . $amount. '</td>';
    }

//....
```

Comment: didn't work direct, I made a few improvements then it worked. Thanks for the tips about using $years from the first query and that array_search did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the returned SQL query into the correct form first.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table abc (category varchar(20), year int, amount varchar(20), program varchar(3));

insert into abc values

('ID FEE' , 1  , '5 USD' , 'SWT'  ),
('TUITION FEE' ,   1  , '50 USD',  'SWT'  ),
('TUITION FEE' ,   2  , '50 USD' ,  'SWT'  ),
('TUITION FEE' ,   3  , '50 USD' ,  'SWT'  ),
('EXAMINATION' ,   2  , '10 USD' ,  'SWT'  );
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
category AS categories, 
group_concat(year) AS years,
group_concat(amount) AS amounts
FROM abc
group by category;
```

| categories | years | amounts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EXAMINATION | 2 | 10 USD |
| ID FEE | 1 | 5 USD |
| TUITION FEE | 1,2,3 | 50 USD,50 USD,50 USD |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2b2HJJGLAFbeVtDuheVqTw/1)

In the PHP, use `if` to place either the amount or an empty cell.